# returning results from functions - javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, callback, return-value

I defined the following Javascript function:

```
function RecoverDataFromTable(table_name) {
              query = "";

              //some code that build a query string from table_name and
              //other arguments given to the function

              function Query(database) {
              database.executeSql(query, [], RecoverResults, Error)
              }

              function RecoverResults(database, results) {
              var my_result = results.rows(0).id;
              // assume this works and store a value to my_result
              }

              function Error(error) {
              //alert something
              }

              function Success() {
              //alert something
              }

              database.transaction(Query, Error, Success)                 

              }
```

Now, how can i return my_result value so i can do this?

```
var my_var = RecoverDataFromTable(table_name, argument1, argument2.....)
```

Thanks in advance.
Ask if you need more explanation. :)

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/6/Working-with-dates-and-SQLite-in-PhoneGap

Comment: **Error** and **Success** are callbacks...  are they asynchronous?

Comment: i'm a beginner so i'm not sure....but i think so..

Comment: Ok ... can you provide any more info on what **database** is?  Seems like it's a JS library.

Comment: that's a web sql database using sql lite. I'm writing a phonegap app on iOs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really set the variable like that, because the function is asynchronous.  Instead, you should include a **callback** function in your request to *RecoverDataFromTable*.  Define it like this:

```
function RecoverDataFromTable(callback, table_name) {
     ...

     function RecoverResults(database, results) {
          var my_result = results.rows(0).id;
          // assume this works and store a value to my_result
          // make the callback:
          callback(result);
     }
     ...
}
```

Then make the call like this:

```
function handleResult(my_result)
{
    // handle the result here
}

RecoverDataFromTable(handleResult, table_name, argument1, argument2.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function  RecoverResults is asynchronous, then you can use to::

```
function RecoverDataFromTable(callback, table_name) {
      ...
      function RecoverResults(callback, database, results) {
          var my_result = results.rows(0).id;
          callback(my_result);
          // assume this works and store a value to my_result
      }
}
RecoverDataFromTable(function(result) {
    var my_var = result;

}, table_name, argument1, argument2.....);
```

Comment: this is very similar to the correct answer. It doesn't work because there's callback in RecoverResults arguments. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

isn't it just?

```
function RecoverResults(database, results) {
 return results.rows(0).id;
}

var my_result = RecoverResults();
```

Comment: No, because it looks like the function is asynchronous ...